# Converting Listener methods with return value into callbackFlow

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

**Update**

This is a better example to give more info about context.

```
interface TransactionStepHandler {

    fun transactionStarted()

    fun cardInserted(cardID: Int): Boolean

    fun transactionEnd(isSuccess: Boolean)

}

class TransactionHandler {

    fun startTransaction(stepHandler: TransactionStepHandler) {
        //
    }

    //Make it suspend
    suspend fun startTransaction(): Boolean = TODO("implement")
}

fun main() {
    TransactionHandler().startTransaction(object : TransactionStepHandler {
        override fun transactionStarted() {
            //Do something
        }

        override fun cardInserted(cardID: Int): Boolean {
            var isCardValid = false
            //Some blocking validations from backend ex: isCardValid = .....
            return isCardValid
        }

        override fun transactionEnd(isSuccess: Boolean) {
            //Do something
        }
    })
}
```

**Question**

If onEvent1 does not require a return value it is easy to convert it into a callbackFlow. But for this case, is there any preferred way to convert this callback into a callbackFlow?

```
class EventHandler {

    fun registerListener(listener: Listener) {
        //...
    }

    interface Listener {
        fun onEvent1(): Int
        fun onEvent2()
    }
}

fun main() {
    EventHandler()
        .registerListener(object : EventHandler.Listener {
            override fun onEvent1(): Int {
                return 0
            }

            override fun onEvent2() {
                //
            }
        })

}
```

Comment: Flows are unidirectional, so this doesn't make sense unless you're okay with returning the same Int value back to the EventHandler every time.

Comment: Even skipping the flow part, why the event listener is returning anything? This seems unusual. What's your use case?

Comment: @broot Lets say card inserted and depending on some other asynchronous flow you will return a value. Think like return 1 means continue transaction and return 0 means cancel transaction. I just made up the names.

Comment: @Tenfour04 That makes sense. Perhaps we should not break unidirectional data flow. Nevertheless I wanted see the ideas & solutions from the community.

Comment: @broot An example of listener that returns something is Java [FileVisitor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/FileVisitor.html). When traversing a file or directory, the listener returns a value to let the path traversal program know if it should stop the traversal, skip siblings or continue traversal normallly.

Comment: It is not clear from the example what you want to emit to the flow, though. The listener return value is for the event handler (so propagated "upstream"). But what do you want to propagate "downstream" ?

Comment: @amanin Tried to provide a better example.